# When is the task added to the event loop?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm fairly comfortable with the asynchronous functionalities of Python (adding tasks to the event loop, `await`ing them etc). However, I've been reading more about it recently and I saw an example which confuses me:

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

start_time = time.time()


async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        for number in range(1, 151):
            pokemon_url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{number}'
            async with session.get(pokemon_url) as resp:
                pokemon = await resp.json()
                print(pokemon['name'])

asyncio.run(main())
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

The above code is supposed to be running concurrently (which it does) but I don't exactly understand how the event loop is organised in this case. My understanding is that the session is created asynchronously, then the `for` loops runs 'sequentially' up to a point.

I'm assuming that `async with session.get`  is what is responsible for adding the tasks to the event loop somehow but how? My version would look something like this:

```py
 async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as group:
        for i in range(x):
            group.create_task(session.get(url))
```

which should be equivalent somehow with the above. So then, how exactly is this done in the first version?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is not quite correct.  There is only one Task here, and that is the object returned by the call to main().  Your code doesn't show this call being made, but I'm assuming that somewhere you are executing a line like:

```
asyncio.run(main())
```

or:

```
asyncio.create_task(main())
```

There are several other ways to create a Task, as documented in the standard docs, but an await expression is not one of them.

Within a Task, an await expression returns control to the event loop.  This occurs in three places in your code.  The obvious one is:

```
await resp.join()
```

The other two awaits occur because of the context manager.  One is the `async with` statement:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
```

which creates an anonymous object with the call `aiohttp.ClientSession()` and then awaits that object's asynchronous function `x.__aenter__()`.

There is a third one.  When you exit the indented block, there is an await on `x.__aexit__()`.

These await expressions are not Tasks, but points *within* a Task where it cooperatively releases control of the event loop, allowing another Task to execute.  That's how asyncio works; it's a cooperative multitasking architecture.

You said that this "code is supposed to be running concurrently (which it does)" but your code does not show a second Task.  Concurrency needs at least two things (Tasks, threads or Processes).  You only show one.

Comment: Technically, there is _no_ task in that session example code by the OP at all. I'd say there _would_ be a task around `main`, _if_ it was called and the resulting coroutine passed to `asyncio.run`. But other than that, this is spot on.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Thanks.  Of course this code, by itself, does nothing at all - so there has to be something more to the story :-)

Comment: I have updated the post to include the main call. However, I still don't really get how the tasks are run asynchronously (which is the case, based on the article from which the code is from), since there is no explicit adding to the event loop now.

Comment: `session.get(url)` is a call to a coroutine, which returns a coroutine object.  As the name implies, `group.create_task()` takes the coroutine object and makes it into a task.  This schedules the task for execution by the event loop.  That execution begins "as soon as possible," which would typically be at the next await expression.  The second code snippet is not equivalent to the first one, since the second one creates multiple tasks and the first one does not.  You say that you updated the post to show the main call, but you didn't actually do that.

Comment: The first snippet is taken straight from the article, which states that the tasks run concurrently. Do they not, afterall? Since for each `number` the coroutine `session.get` runs and then `resp.json` is immediately awaited (meaning the `main` coroutine blocks). Basically, how can there be another `get` request scheduled while one is being `await`ed, considering that blocks and waits for each iteration of the `for` loop to end before going onto the next?

Comment: OK, I figured the code doesn't actually run concurrently ;) It's just that aiohttp is faster than the requests library in the sequential version.

Comment: In the first snippet, the statement "the tasks run concurrently" doesn't make sense, since there aren't multiple Tasks being shown.  In fact the first snippet does not actually show the creation of *any* Tasks; that must occur in some other piece of code.  In any case, as you correctly point out, the code forces the get() calls to run sequentially.  No matter how you launch that code, it will not execute the get() calls in parallel.